# flashcard software for vocabularies?

Tags: software-recommendation

I am a Chinese learning English. I am wondering is there some software that can help me to remember vocabularies?

I know there is software called SuperMemo which is commercial software. Is there some alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

For KDE: [KWordQuiz](http://edu.kde.org/applications/language/kwordquiz/)

[image: kwordquiz]

Others: [Anki](http://ankisrs.net/index.html)

[image: Anki]

You can install both of them from repositories.